# IBM Watson Assistant: How to detect conversation is coming from Slack or Web based integration

Tags: ibm-cloud, slack, watson-assistant

I want to be able to return HTML formatted text when the user is coming in via a web based interface.  This works great, but if you integrate with Slack, you get just pure HTML dumped on the user.  I'm using the out of the box, Watson Assistant supplied web and slack integrations.  Is there a way to detect which integration is driving the conversation?

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions to this issue.  Tried them both.

**Option 1:**
First one is using the JSON Editor to specify formatting, thanks to data_henrik for his response https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-responses-json#dialog-responses-json-target-integrations.  Two things to keep in mind when using this solution:

1. The when you do "Try Me", you will see multiple responses.  One for each format you send back.
2. You will need to have the webhook pass back multiple formats for each channel you are targeting.
3. The format that is presented in the documentation is out of date.  Here is the format I figured out to put in the JSON Editor.

JSON Editor

```
{
    "output": {
        "generic": [{
                "response_type": "text",
                "channels": [{
                    "channel": "chat"
                }],
                "values": [{
                    "text": "$webhook_result_2.chat"
                }],
                "selection_policy": "sequential"
            },
            {
                "response_type": "text",
                "channels": [{
                    "channel": "slack"
                }],
                "values": [{
                    "text": "$webhook_result_2.slack"
                }],
                "selection_policy": "sequential"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**
The second option was to have a user defined variable set via the chat client, have that passed in on webhook call.  The code would then use that to know what format to apply.  Not as elegant, but uses less network bandwidth and processing to build responses.

updated web client script that Watson provides:

```
  <script>
    function preSendhandler(event) {
      event.data.context.skills['main skill'].user_defined.client = "html";
    }

    window.watsonAssistantChatOptions = {
      integrationID: "...", // The ID of this integration.
      region: "...", // The region your integration is hosted in.
      serviceInstanceID: "...", // The ID of your service instance.
      onLoad: function (instance) {
        // Subscribe to the "pre:send" event.
        instance.on({
          type: "pre:send",
          handler: preSendhandler
        });
        instance.render();
      }
    };
    setTimeout(function () {
      const t = document.createElement('script');
      t.src = "https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.appdomain.cloud/loadWatsonAssistantChat.js";
      document.head.appendChild(t);
    });
  </script>
```

You will also need to pass that user defined variable into the webhook by setting the parameter to the webhook of "client" and value "$client".

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer by pointing out that Watson Assistant offer various ways of [how to compose a response](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-overview#dialog-overview-responses). There are simple responses and more complex ("rich") responses plus images, options, pauses and more. Moreover, you can [define the responses in the JSON editor](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-responses-json).

The latter allows to [create native JSON responses and to address specific output channels](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-responses-json#dialog-responses-json-native). Therefore, you could define responses specific to Slack and even use the advanced formatting options offered by Slack, not just plain text.

In conclusions, you don't need to detect where the input is coming from, but design the output for your utilized output channels. A different view, but the same or even better result... :)

Comment: I have not looked recently, but I understand that there could be flags within the context element of the message that tracks where the conversation input originated from. This could then be used to trigger different responses.

Comment: The documentation you pointed to is out of date.  The structure of the JSON object has changed.  I added as an answer to this question as comments are limited in size and formatting.